# How can i identify how many nouns should be followed after a certain verb?

Tags: nlp

I am trying on semi-automatically generating a nltk.ccg lexicon(or dictionary), and maybe it is CCG supertagging. BiLSTM-CRF may be a good method; but i expect one not depending one deep networks.

I come up with a method to use part-of-speech identify tools like nltk.pos_tag() and use a pre-defined dictionary to turn it into its corresponding nltk.ccg part.

But i am stuck in the part of **verb**: Some verbs like "arrive" should follow no verb; some should follow one like "cook"; some should follow two, for example "give" should follow somebody and something. Here is an example division of verbs from nltk.ccg documentation:

```
lex = lexicon.fromstring('''
...     :- S, NP, N, VP
...     TV :: VP/NP
...     DTV :: TV/NP
...
...     be => TV
...     cook => TV
...     eat => TV
...
...     give => DTV
```

But the different types of NLTK Pos-tag() is like this, identified by times:

```
VB  verb, base form take
VBD verb, past tense    took
VBG verb, gerund/present participle taking
VBN verb, past participle   taken
VBP verb, sing. present, non-3d take
VBZ verb, 3rd person sing. present  takes
```

How can i use alternative nlp tools to fix this problem?
I know about HMM and Viterbi algorithm to train a new Pos-tag model but it seems to costful for me. If no way to fix it, i will give each verb these three roles:

```
     VP
     TV :: VP/NP
     DTV :: TV/NP
```

to tag them and use CCG parsing process to verify each one and decide which is the correct result.